# Конвертация aac в wav python

Tags: python, конвертация, python-3.9, wav

Как конвертировать aac формат в wav внутри python скрипта?
Я примерно понимаю как конвертировать в командной строке, но вообще не понимаю как сделать через скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того,чтобы использовать у вас должно быть загружено:
pydub (включая AudioSegment)
ffmpeg https://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

wav_audio = AudioSegment.from_file("file.aac", format="aac")


wav_audio.export("file.mp3", format="mp3")
```